# GraphQL nested mutation + Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-client, mutation

I am using graphQL, sequelize and nodejs with apollo client.
The data which I am sending from the UI is a nested structure of the following form:

> ### Grandparent
>
> ### Parent
>
> Child

So a grandparent can have one or more parents and a parent can have one or more children.

I am trying to update my SQLite database, created using sequelize, using one GraphQL mutation. I am able to create a mutation with a flat structure:

schema.gql file contents ->

```
type Mutation Family(
    grandParentName: String,
    grandParentHeight: String,
    Parent: String,
)
```

but I want something along the lines of

```
type Mutation CreateNestedFamily(
    grandParentName: String,
    grandParentHeight: String,
    Parent: CreateParent(
           parentName: String,
           parentHeight: String
           child: CreateChild(
                 childName: String,
                 childHeight: String
                 )
            )
)
```

But I dont know how to achieve this and the graphql documentation around nested mutations is very limited.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've phrased you problem is a little strange, but i'll do my best to point you in the right direction.

There's no such thing as a nested mutation in GraphQL, but you can construct input types that allows an arbitrary nesting of data that you pass to a single mutation.

I'll step back from your approach and take a specific problem "I want to create a person and their descendants"

```
input PersonInput {
  name: String!
  height: String!
  children: [PersonInput!]
}

type Mutation {
  createPerson(person: PersonInput!): SomeOutputType
}
```

Hopefully you can see the recursive nature of this structure. It'd be more difficult to impose a limit on this, i.e to only allow 3 levels deep.

Comment: Thanks - specifying input types as you suggested fixed my problem